# URL base changing after using any controller with parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

i'm having an problem with the URL of Codeigniter.
When i use one controller with parameter, example: `localhost/ci/products/news` (where `localhost/ci` is the url base), after i click in any element `<a />`, example: `<a href="home"/>` Codeigniter redirects for `localhost/ci/products/home` and no for `localhost/ci/home`.

Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a base_url for links. Right now your anchor has a relative path in the href="home", you should have full path in your links, when u use mod_rewrite for nice urls.

like

```
 <a href="https://your.server/ci/home">Home </a>
```

Comment: If this answer solved you problem, then please accept the solution. There are many questions in stackoverflow that have been resolved but not accepted.